# An exercise on isomorphic groups of order 24

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am a beginning learner of group theory.

Which of the following are isomorphic:$$\mathbb{Z_{24}}, D_{4}\times \mathbb{Z_{3}},A_{4}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}},\mathbb{Z_{2}}\times D_{6}, \mathbb{Z_{12}}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}},D_{12}, S_{4}$$

I know $\mathbb{Z_{24}}$ is cyclic and none of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}},D_{12}, S_{4}$ are cyclic since none has an element of order 24. I also know $D_{12}$ and $S_{4}$ are not isomorphic because $S_{4}$ has no element of order 12. Finally, I know $A_{4}$ and $D_{6}$ are also not isomorphic because $D_{6}$, unlike $A_{4}$, contains an element of order 6.

Other than this I don't know how to proceed. Any hints are appreciated. Please allow me to do the work.

Comment: @kklm, not by a long sight.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, From a beginner's perspective, I can see why kk lm's suggestion would be a neat idea: since $A_{4} <S_{4}$ and it's exactly half of $S_{4}$, we could map those elements of $S_{4}$ which coincide with those of $A_{4}$ into pairs of the form $(\alpha,0)$, where $\alpha \in A_{4}$, and all those in $S_{4} - A_{4}$ into pairs of the form $(\alpha,1)$. Ultimately, this fails since multiplication of $(\alpha,0)$ with $(\alpha,1)$ doesn't produce an element of $A_{4}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$

Comment: My problem was with the "I would say..." clause. I would have said something like "Can you decide whether..." But if you're happy with this, it's ok, and I will remove my comment.

Comment: To me, "I would say that" means "I believe that".

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z_{24}}$ is the only cyclic one - all other groups are non-abelian except $\mathbb{Z_{12}}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$, which you noted is not cyclic.

Among the remaining ones, $\mathbb{Z_{12}}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$ is the only abelian one, so this is out too.

If you have already seen the center of a group, you may proceed as follows.

Among the remaining ones, $S_{4}$ is the only centerless one ($Z(S_{4}) = 1$).

Now you should know that $D_{2 k}$ has a center of order $2$. Then $D_{4}\times \mathbb{Z_{3}}$ is the only one with a center of order $6$, and $\mathbb{Z_{2}}\times D_{6}$ is the only one with a center of order $4$.

We are left with $A_{4}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$ and $D_{12}$. But the latter has an element of order $12$, while the former does not. In fact, if $a \in A_{4}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$ has order $12$, then $a^{2} \in A_{4}$ has order $6$, and you know this is not the case.

Comment: Grazie @Andreas Caranti. While the concept of a group centre is easy to grasp, it's a few sections ahead in my book and don't want to assume it just yet. Is there another more elementary route you could suggest?

Comment: Will try and reformulate in terms of orders.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean orders of individual elements correct?

Comment: Yes, as you were using the concept in your post.

Comment: Can you use normal subgroups?

Comment: No, but I will reformulate in terms of your suggestion. I was under the assumption that at least one pair was isomorphic since the question asked "which of the following are isomorphic to each other". Thank you once again.

Comment: I am not immune to mistakes, will double check.